# gwt resource bundle

Tags: gwt, resources, internationalization

I am looking for a solution in GWT to bundle properties file, like i do in java.util.ResourceBundle

```
        ResourceBundle messageBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(baseName.properties , new Locale(language));
        Set<String> messagesKey = messageBundle.keySet();
        Map<String, String> messagesMap = new HashMap<String, String> (messagesKey.size());
        for (String key : messagesKey) {
            messagesMap.put(key, messageBundle.getString(key));
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing to it is [ContstantsWithLookup](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/ConstantsWithLookup.html) (but you can't get list of keys from it) or [Dictionary](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Dictionary.html) (but it doesn't work with *.properties files, only with js objects)

Answer (score 1):

To use resource bundle on client side just use Messages interface.

1) Define your interface MyMessages in client package

```
public interface MyMessages extends Messages {
    String hello(String username);
    String bye(String username);
    String empty();

}
```

2) Create properties file\files beside your interface MyMessages.properties and MyMessages_ru.properties for example. Properties keys must be equals methods names.

```
hello=Hello {0}, how are you?
bye=Bye-bye {0}!
empty=Just message!
```

3) Create your messages object in gwt module

```
MyMessages messages = GWT.create(MyMessages .class);
```

4) Use messages

```
new AlertMessageBox("", messages.empty()).show();
```

Also you can define default messages via annotations right in your interface code, for example

```
public interface MyMessages extends Messages {

    @DefaultMessage("Hello {0}, how are you?") 
    String hello(String username);

    @DefaultMessage("Bye-bye {0}!") 
    String bye(String username);

    @DefaultMessage("Just message!") 
    String empty();

}
```